# How many discplies really there with ramanjurchurya sage

Tags: sri-vaishnava

How many discplies where really with ramanjurcharya and what is their names 48 dicplies or 74 discplies?

Comment: Again same question!!!

Comment: Let me tell. Please wait after asking a question!!!! It may take sometime to answer!! Asking again and again is not going to help!

Comment: I have lot of confusions please clariffy dobut It my humble request

Comment: Your doubts will be clarified but you have to wait!!

Comment: Ok sir I will surely wait but answer me fast as possible

Comment: Ok sir I will surely wait

Comment: There's no gurantee when answer will come. Lots of old questions have been answered a year late too!! So please wait. Dont post repetitive questions please! Because its of no use as it ll be closed!

Comment: Please answer my question

Comment: I dont know the answer. Someone will answer!! So wait till it is answered!

Comment: @L.AravindKalaimani I have just answered your original question. Kindly check that